# How can I read file loaded in a variable in guile?

Tags: scheme, guile

I am new to to guile and scheme and what I am trying to do right now is take a scheme file  (*file.scm*) and load it up into a variable so I will be able to parse it, and I am having trouble finding how to do this anywhere.

What I have right now is

```
(define var (load "file.scm")) ; loads file scheme
```

but I am unsure how to start reading the lines.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`load` parses and runs the scheme code in a file. If you just want to read a file, use `open-input-file`.

```
(define file (open-input-file "file address here"))
(display (read-line file))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to read an entire file as a string, there's a function for that in the [textual-ports](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Textual-I_002fO.html#Textual-I_002fO) module. You'd use it something like:

```
(define contents (call-with-input-file "file.txt" get-string-all))
```

(You can use `call-with-input-file` and `with-input-from-file` to avoid having to manually open and close a file port, which is handy)